# Data Structures: My program crashes when I try to pop my data out of the stack

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on a Data Structures assignment focused on stacks and I need help.
I'm supposed to compare two strings if they are palindrome using a stack.

My idea of this program is to fgets() a string. Clear the spaces and store it in char "o" then push each char into a stack, pop them out into another set of char "r" and check if(o == r).

However, when I compile I get a warning, which the program worked fine with it. 
Further down into my program, when I try to pop my char back out, the program crashes.

I'm curious what causes that warning in my code and how to fix it.
Most important I want to understand what I am doing wrong to cause my program to crash when I pop my data out of the satck.

**The warning:**

```
main.c:28:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
       dataPtr = (char*)s[c];
```

**What I get when it crashes:**

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**My attached Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stacksADT.h"

int main (void)
{
  char s[50];
  char o[50];
  char r[50];

  STACK* stack;
  char* dataPtr;

  stack = createStack();

  printf("Enter the string to compare:\n");
  fgets(s,50, stdin);

  for(int c = 0; c < strlen(s); c++){
    if( s[c] != ' ' ){
      dataPtr = (char*)s[c];
      printf("%s", dataPtr);
      pushStack( stack, dataPtr );
    }
  }

  for(int c = 0; c < strlen(o); c++){
    printf("%s", (char*)popStack(stack));
  }

} // main
```

**My popStack() operation:**

```
void* popStack (STACK* stack)
{
  // Local Definitions
  void* dataOutPtr;
  STACK_NODE* temp;

  // Statements
  if(stack->count == 0)
    dataOutPtr = NULL;
  else
  {
    temp = stack->top;
    dataOutPtr = stack->top->dataPtr;
    stack->top = stack->top->link;
    free(temp);
    (stack->count)--;
  } // else
  return dataOutPtr;
} // popStack
```

Comment: don't ignore the warning:  `dataPtr = (char*)s[c];` is wrong. It should be `dataPtr = s+c;`

Comment: try to comment free(temp) and execute, what's up?

Comment: Here `dataPtr = (char*)s[c];` remove the cast and fix the code. Assigning the value of a `char` (`s[c]`) to a pointer (`dataPtr`) does not make any sense at all.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: In C there are very, very, very few cases you explicitly need to cast. Do not use casting to silence the compiler. This `printf("%s", (char*)popStack(stack));` is one of these rare cases ... :-)

Comment: OT: Those `for(int c = ...`s should be `for(size_t c = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s[c]` returns a char. You simply cast it to a pointer. Assigning to a pointer `char *dataPtr` is wrong, you need to pass it a reference. Use either of these two:

- `dataPtr = &(s[c])`
- `dataPtr = s+c`

Comment: So I'm was under the impression that `&(s[c])` points at the address of a specific character like an array. But I seem to get everything after that character. For example "Go Dog" with `&(s[2])` gives me " dog".  I just need one letter returned. Is my assumption correct? If so, how would I change it to just get only one character.

Comment: Your impression is correct. To get ith character in string of length l, just, do s[i-1]